# Prove by mathematical induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} $

Tags: induction

Prove by mathematical induction that:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} $$

**Step 1:** Show that the statement is true for $n = 1$:

LHS = $$\frac{(-1)^{1+1}}{1} = 1$$

RHS = $$\frac{1}{1} = 1$$

**Step 2:** Show that "if true for n = p, then true for n = p + 1":

Starting with the LHS of equality for $n = p + 1$ and try to get to the RHS by using the equality for $n = p$. Simplifying:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2(p+1)} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2p+2} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$

Breaking out the first two term:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2p+2} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{2p+3}}{2p+2} + \frac{(-1)^{2p+2}}{2p+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{2p} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} $$

The last term can now be exchanged for the RHS in the original equality:

$$\frac{(-1)^{2p+3}}{2p+2} + \frac{(-1)^{2p+2}}{2p+1} + \sum_{k=1}^{2p} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{2p+3}}{2p+2} + \frac{(-1)^{2p+2}}{2p+1} + \sum_{k=p+1}^{2p} \frac{1}{k}$$

Since $2p+3$ is odd and $2p+2$ is even, we get:

$$\frac{(-1)}{2p+2} + \frac{1}{2p+1} + \sum_{k=p+1}^{2p} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{(-1)}{2p+2} + \sum_{k=p+1}^{2p+1} \frac{1}{k}$$

...because we can easily absorb the second term in the third term sum. However, I am stuck here because the first term is negative. I probably made a trivial error somewhere, but I am unable to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your step 1 is wrong. When $n=1$, on the LHS your sum will have two terms since you're summing to $2n$, and on RHS you will have $k=2$.

Comment: Check your base case.  Your sum on the LHS is from 1 to 2 and the sum on the RHS is from 2 to 2.  This results in a very different base case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go from $n=p$ to $n=p+1$, what you want to show is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2(p+1)} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k={\color{red}{(p+1)}}+1}^{2(p+1)} \frac{1}{k}. $$

The crucial part I think you're overlooking is in red. To get the desired result, you have to pull the first term out of your sum $\sum_{k=p+1}^{2p+1} \frac{1}{k}$.

$$\begin{align}\\
\frac{(-1)}{2p+2} + \sum_{k=p+1}^{2p+1} \frac{1}{k} &= \frac{-1}{2p+1} + \frac{1}{p+1} + \sum_{k=p+2}^{2p+1} \frac{1}{k},\\
&= \frac{-1}{2p+2} +\frac{2}{2p+2} + \sum_{k=p+2}^{2p+1} \frac{1}{k}, \\
&= \frac{1}{2p+2} + \sum_{k=p+2}^{2p+1} \frac{1}{k}, \\
&= \sum_{k=p+2}^{2p+2} \frac{1}{k}.\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}$.

Consider how each side changes
when you go from $n$
to $n+1$.

The left side goes from
$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$
to
$\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
$.
This changes by
$\sum_{k=2n+1}^{2n+2} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
=\frac{(-1)^{2n+2}}{2n+1}+\frac{(-1)^{2n+3}}{2n+2}
=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}
=\frac{(2n+2)-(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
$.

The right side changes from
$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}$
to
$\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2} \frac{1}{k}$.
The difference is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2} \frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}
&=(\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}+\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2})
-(\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k})\\
&=(\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2})-(\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\frac{(2n+2)(n+1)+(2n+1)(n+1)-(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{(2n^2+4n+2)+(2n^2+3n+1)-(4n^2+6n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
\end{array}
$

These two are the same,
so the two sums change by the same amount when
$n$ goes from
$n$ to $n+1$.

Notice how the
key step in getting the difference
for the right side
was finding the terms in the two sums
that have the same range of indices
so they can be cancelled out.
The first sum goes from
$n+2$ to $2n+2$,
and the second goes from
$n+1$ to $2n$.
What they have in common is
$n+2$ to $2n$.
The first sum has,
in addition to the common terms,
$2n+1$ and $2n+2$
(at the top);
the second sum has
$n+1$
(at the bottom).
When the two are subtracted,
only the $2n+1$, $2n+2$,
and $n+1$ terms
are left.

This is a very common step when
doing this type of problem
and you should practice
to get comfortable with this.

Note:
I realize after writing this
that the computation of
the difference of the right side
could be simpler,
like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2} \frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}
&=(\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}+\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2})
-(\frac1{n+1}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k})\\
&=(\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2})-(\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\frac{(2n+2)+(2n+1)-2(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&=\frac{(4n+3)-(4n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
\end{array}
$